# Skip nodes during binary tree traversal

Tags: java, language-agnostic, binary-tree, tree-traversal, cluster-analysis

I need to traverse a binary tree, skipping the children of any node for which a condition is met.

This implements a tree-guided clustering approach; the leaves of a subtree are considered a cluster when they collectively meet the condition.

It seems like the place to start would be pre-order traversal, but I'm not sure how to modify the algorithm to skip all the children of the current node.

**Update**

In addition to the two (correct) answers below, one can use the following Java libraries:

- [MyArch TreeIter](http://myarch.com/treeiter) - Generic (with adapter class) tree traversal, with child skipping and dynamic maximum traversal depth
- [Phylosoft Forester](http://www.phylosoft.org/forester/) - Tree implementation with `getAllExternalDescendants` and a Newick-to-XML converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by skipping all the children you mean not just direct descendants but their entire subtrees, you can do the following:

```
public void traverse(Node n){
    if (n==null)
        return;
    doSomethingWith(n);
    if (!conditionIsMet(n)){
        traverse(n.left);
        traverse(n.right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, obvious in retrospect (as is so often the case). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the first part is easy:

```
class Tree {
    Tree(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    Tree left, right;
    Object object;
    int data;
}
public class Main {
    static void myPreorder(Tree tree) {
        if (tree == null) return;
        if (tree.data > 2) {
            System.out.println("skipping " + tree.data);
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("visiting " + tree.data);
        myPreorder(tree.left);
        myPreorder(tree.right);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tree root = new Tree(1);
        root.left = new Tree(2);
        root.right = new Tree(3);
        root.right.left = new Tree(4);
        root.right.right = new Tree(5);
        myPreorder(root);
    }
}
```

the second part: " ... the leaves of a subtree are considered a cluster when they collectively meet the condition. ..." is hard. you would need to examine all of the leaves of a node to see that they met the skip condition.

Comment: Yeah, one needs a `getAllLeafDescendents` method. The tree I'm using has such a method and each of my leaf nodes has a pairwise distance to every other leaf node, known from out-of-band sources, so it's not terribly difficult.